# Custom Field populated via send_flow is blank

Tags: surveymonkey

[This page in the API docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/send_flow) indicates that the *collector.recipients[_].custom_id* field should be populated with a string. However, when executing a call against the send_flow endpoint to create recipients, that field ends up blank. When I execute my call against the send_flow endpoint, the following things all happen:

- My collector is created in the correct survey with the correct options.
- My recipients' emails, first names, and last names are all populated correctly.
- My email message is created correctly.
- There's definitely a string value in that field in my JSON object, and it is named correctly according to the API docs, but the Custom Data field for each recipient contains an empty value.
- The API returns no errors.

So I know the API call is working, and I can't seem to get it to return an error or an explanation as to why the Custom Data field is empty for each recipient.

But then in [this documentation for the SM GUI](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Custom-Data), I see that I can now have up to six custom fields:

```
[CustomData1]
[CustomData2]
[CustomData3]
[CustomData4]
[CustomData5]
[CustomData6]
```

That wasn't there a couple months ago. So has something recently changed in regards to the behavior of custom recipient fields? Is the API documentation out of date?

More to the point: how do I populate these custom data fields via the send_flow endpoint of the API?

Comment: There has been some changes to custom data recently - definitely hit up api-support@surveymonkey.com with this, they should be able to help you.

Comment: Email support has been contacted. Will post the solution if we arrive at one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include 'custom_id' in the send_flow API request, that value will be available in the response payload of the [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) request.  It is also available in the 'Custom Data' field when viewing individual responses, or in an export of responses from the SM UI.  The one place this value is not currently available is in the UI for displaying the list of recipients, but will be added back soon.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. The same thing was confirmed by email support. I'm able to work around that limitation for now, and look forward to having API support for the additional custom data fields soon.